# How to make returned value of Button to "OK"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, return-value

using c#, WinForms, .net FrameWork 4.5 VS 2012

Try to create small programm. Currently try to use something like

```
 private void buttonAddNewEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewEntry a = new AddNewEntry();
        if (a.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            carInStock.Add(a.myCar);
        }
        UpdateGrid();
    }
```

But in my WinForm i haven't button OK, **question** - How can i set returned result of my button as OK?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the text of the button that fires this event?

Comment: Are you trying to use one event for multiple buttons?

Comment: No i mean i want to get returned value for code `DialogResult.OK`, that can be true

Comment: @Brandon - no i use few one `button`s - name one of it  - `buttonAddToGrid` I want that if someone press button Dialog result became as `DialogResult.OK`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming I understand that you're not actually making the button the OK result (assigning it as the [Form.AcceptButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), but want it to return said result:

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
this.Close();
```

[Form.DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can be assigned to (and therefore returned) when the dialog's closed.

I should mention though: your question, as it stands, is very unclear though. Maybe if you could show more code (what you're trying for and what you've accomplished) a better answer could be provided.